# Passing data to new GUI

Tags: swing, oop, user-interface, jframe

I have a `JTable` with contents on it which I have read from a CSV file. I am using the following method which when I click on a row it will open up a new `JFrame` and close the previous one. It will display things such as ID, co-ordinates, status of what is written on that table and can edit them if wanted. E.G. table below:

```
|ID  |co-ordinates      | status   | 
| 1  |   (3,21)          |  pending | 
|  2 |  (4,21)           | full     | 
|  3 |  (9, 12)          |  empty   |
```

If I click row 1, it will pop up with frame of the ID(1), co ordinates(3,21) and status in a text field in another frame and is editable. I am able to do the clicking function but am not sure how to take that data onto the next frame when clicking the row.

```
 //in location class
 table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                  if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    AddEdit An = new AddEdit(); //goes to next class 
                    An.setVisible(true);
                    dispose();
                }
             }
          });
```

How to take that data onto the next frame, when clicking the row?

Comment: *"..open up a new JFrame and close the previous one."* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Instead use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: BTW - given this is a Q&A site, I added an actual question in the form of *"How to take that data onto the next frame, when clicking the row?"* Please don't forget to add a question.

Comment: yup will change up question thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what type of content your `JTable` has, I can only offer a generic solution.

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
int userID = (Integer) table.getValueAt(row, 0);
// is co-ordinates [sic] a String or a Point? 
// You can do the same as for userID and use (row,1) to get the value
String status = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 2)
```

With this you can i.e. create an `Object[]` and send this to the constructor of `AddEdit` or write a method `getJTableObject()` or something similar in `AddEdit`. This depends on wether you can change `AddEdit` or not.

You also should consider Andrews advice and use the cardLayout. With this you could for instance use an [`ObserverPattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and send your object around.

---

Another way is using a `JOptionPane`:

```
Object[] message = { "Please update the information:", newStatusPanel };
int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, "Update information",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

`newStatusPanel` simply is a `JPanel` on which you put i.e. `JTextFields`. You then fill those fields with the content from the `JTable` by the method I have shown earlier and when the user clicks okay, you update the `JTable`.

```
// Do something with the result
if (response == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
model.addRow(new Object[] { txtID.getText(), coordinates.getText(), ... });
```

This looks like this:

[image: UpdateStatus]

(PS: I will later change the text-based passwords to hash-based. Please ignore this blatant unsecure way of dealing with passwords)